# htaccess /en works normal but /en/ gives page cannot be found

Tags: .htaccess

when browsing [www.mywebsite.com/en](http://www.mywebsite.com/en)   or  [www.mywebsite.com/fr](http://www.mywebsite.com/fr) it works fine, if browsing with / at the end of any, it gives page cannot be found

i'm using the htaccess code below:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^fr$ index.php
RewriteRule ^en$ index_en.php

RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ $1_en.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
RewriteRule ^fr$ index.php
RewriteRule ^en$ index_en.php
```

With

```
RewriteRule ^fr/?$ index.php
RewriteRule ^en/?$ index_en.php
```